# Are shopping cart and paypal 2 different things?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Are shopping cart and paypal 2 different things ? And how to implement them in ASP.NET

Comment: Shopping cart is a general term in e-commerce and its simply where you build your order(fill your cart), Paypal is an online payment service that you could use to pay for the order in your shopping cart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Shopping cart and paypal are two different things.
Paypal is an online payment service which you can use to pay online on a website. Shopping cart is a general term which is used to store items you want to purchase.
If you want to build a shopping website in asp.net, Have a look at http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-a-simple-paypal-shop.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Official Paypal documentation is here:
https://www.x.com/index.jspa

There are several code samples available.

Comment: Wow thats a horrible suspicious looking URL. I would have mistken that for a phishing site long before I associated it with paypal.

Answer (score 1):

- Shopping cart deals with answering:  "How does the user indicate multiple items they want to purchase at one time?"
- Paypal deals with answering:  "How does the user pay for their purchase?"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to integrate the PayPal checkout button with ASP.NET and get around the single form problem (also shows how to grab the cart items data):

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/27/Integrate-PayPal-Checkout-Button-with-ASPNET-20.aspx